# Invalid syntax is in the most

Tags: python, syntax, integer, calculator, new-operator

im pretty new to python and im trying to make an if else statement on an operation in my basic calculator and it keeps saying i have an invalid syntax could i get some help from anyone?

This is the code, im sorry for the bad splitting, i am new!

```
num1 = int(input("Prvi broj"))
print(num1)
num2 = int(input("Drugi Broj"))
print(num2)
operacija = int(input("Za Sabiranje, stavite 1, a za Oduzimanje stavite bilo koji drugi broj"))
if operacija = 1:
    print(num1 + num2)
else
    print(num1 - num2)
```

Comment: The new-operator tag is not needed here. You are not dealing with dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if operacija = 1:
```

You are using the wrong operator. `=` is assignment, but you want `==`, comparison for equality. So, change it to this:

```
if operacija == 1:
```

Also, you are missing a colon after `else`. It should be `else:`

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `==` instead of `=`. Also your else should have a colon after.

```
num1 = int(input("Prvi broj"))     
print(num1) 
num2 = int(input("Drugi Broj")) 
print(num2) 
operacija = int(input("Za Sabiranje, stavite 1, a za Oduzimanje stavite bilo koji drugi broj")) 
if operacija = 1: 
    print(num1 + num2) 
else:
    print(num1 - num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to check that if the user types a 1 then you want to add the 2 values.
To do this - you must use 2 Equal signs instead of one.
A single = means assignment to a variable whereas == checks for equality

```
num1 = int(input("Prvi broj"))
print(num1)
num2 = int(input("Drugi Broj")) 
print(num2) 
operacija = int(input("Za Sabiranje, stavite 1, a za Oduzimanje stavite bilo koji drugi broj")) 
if operacija == 1: 
    print(num1 + num2) 
else:
    print(num1 - num2)
```